# I get an error trying to start Spyder after doing a "conda update --all"

Tags: linux-mint, spyder

This is the error I get when starting Spyder from a terminal window:

```
$ spyder
QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/
start.py", line 205, in main
mainwindow.main()
File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/
mainwindow.py", line 3734, in main
mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/
mainwindow.py", line 3590, in run_spyder
main.setup()
File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/
mainwindow.py", line 977, in setup
'spyder.plugins.{}'.format(plugin_name))
File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line
127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in
_find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in
_call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/
plugins/pylint/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
from .plugin import Pylint as PLUGIN_CLASS
File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/
plugins/pylint/plugin.py", line 29, in <module>
from spyder.plugins.pylint.confpage import PylintConfigPage
File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/
plugins/pylint/confpage.py", line 16, in <module>
from spyder.plugins.pylint.widgets.pylintgui import PylintWidget
File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/
plugins/pylint/widgets/pylintgui.py", line 37, in <module>
from spyder.plugins.pylint.utils import get_pylintrc_path
File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/
plugins/pylint/utils.py", line 16, in <module>
import pylint.config
File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pylint/
config.py", line 54, in <module>
import toml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toml'
[1:1:0100/000000.345716:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(41)] Invalid node
channel message
[1:1:0100/000000.345673:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(41)] Invalid node
channel message
```

Answer (score 1):

I installed toml and the error went away:

```
conda install -c anaconda toml
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `pip3 install toml` helped.

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are
better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).